Is this part of the definition of the complex exponential function redundant?
In the real number system, the function $e^x$ is, and can in fact be defined as, the unique differentiable function whose derivative is itself and whose value at $0$ is $1$. But, in the books I have read, in the complex number system, there is an additional condition, namely, "is periodic with period $2 \pi i$". I am wondering whether that additional condition is redundant. Or are there in fact complex differentiable functions besides $e^x$ whose derivative is itself and whose value at $0$ is $1$, but which does not have period $2\pi i$?

No, the first 2 conditions are sufficient. Let $e^z$ denote the usual exponential and let $f(z)$ be an entire function such that $f'(z)=f(z)$ and $f(0)=1$. Furthermore let $h(z)=f(z)e^{-z}$. Then $h'(z)=f'(z)e^{-z}-f(z)e^{-z}=f(z)e^{-z}-f(z)e^{-z}=0$ so $h(z)=C$. But $h(0)=f(0)e^{-0}=1$ so $h(z)=1$. Thus $f(z)=e^z$.

@Snared: Are you asking what "Let $e^x$ denote the usual exponential" means? In this context, I think the answer is presupposing that there exists a well-defined "usual exponential," but that's hardly a problem because we can appeal to the "usual" Taylor expansion, or Euler's formula etc. Importantly, this answer is not a definition itself, it's an argument relating to the definition given in the question. If the answer were purporting to provide a definition of the exponential, then the word "usual" would be more problematic.
